# why scripts are not loaded in using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load `script` and `link` using javascript.Previously I was using `jquery` not I am removing `jquery` from our project only using javascript.

previously I write like this

```
   $('head link[data-reqjq][rel=preload]').each(function(){
      var a = document.createElement('script');
      a.async=false;
      a.src=$(this).attr('href');
      this.parentNode.insertBefore(a, this);
    });
  $(function(){
    $('script[data-reqjq][data-src]').each(function(){
      this.async=true;
      this.src=$(this).data('src');
    });
  });
```

Now I am trying to load both things using `javascript`.

like this but it is not loading

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('head link[data-reqjq][rel=preload]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){
  var a = document.createElement('script');
  a.async=false;
  a.src=this.getAttribute('href');
  this.parentNode.insertBefore(a, this);
});

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('script[data-reqjq][data-src]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){
  el.async=true;
  el.src=el.data('src');
});
```

here is my code

https://jsbin.com/havuxujixi/3/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - add a end tag to the script; `</script>` instead of `/>` ([check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984/5953610))

2 - your second query selector have an error in its callback : `.data('src')` should be `.getAttribute('src')`

also as a suggestion use simple `forEach` instead of `Array.prototype.call`

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('script[data-reqjq][data-src]');
elements.forEach(function(el, i){
  el.async=true;
  el.src=el.getAttribute('src');

});
```

the first selector can be written as:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('head link[data-reqjq][rel=preload]');
elements.forEach(function(el, i){
  var a = document.createElement('script');
  a.async=false;
  a.src=el.getAttribute('href');
  // mounting new one inplace
  el.parentNode.append(a);
  // unmouting the old one
  el.remove();
});
```

Comment: what about  first `head link[data-reqjq][rel=preload`???? is it correct

Comment: I didnt test that since there wasn't a match in html snippet provided, I'll do now.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution

```js
/*
 add JS File 
*/
function addJsFileFunc(filename) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML.toString().includes(filename + ".js"))
        loadScript('/',filename + ".js");
}

addJsFileFunc("paht/script-file-name.js")




/*
 script tag
*/
let scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptTag.src = 'url.js';    

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Comment: `document.head('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);` should be `document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);`